# bash awk - how to extract single characters from this line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the following lines from lmstat output:

```
Users of ccmpsuite:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 1 license in use)

  "ccmpsuite" v2016.03, vendor: cdlmd
  floating license

    <username> <nodename> /dev/tty (v2015.02) (<hostname>/1999 436), start Fri 7/17 21:41
```

I would like to somehow extract the '2' and the '1' out of the first line to get total licenses issued and total licenses in use, to use it elsewhere. So far as I can see, lmstat does not support any minimum-text or xml outputs. I know that I can awk the entire line using this:

```
awk '/^[ ]*Users of[ ]*/'
```

How would I got about extracting the '1' and the '2'?

Comment: Use the `{action}` block for that pattern to print out the appropriate fields (`$6` and `$11` or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with awk:

```
awk '/Users of ccmpsuite:/{print $6,$11}' input.txt
2 1
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ "Users of ccmpsuite:" ]]
    then
        match=($line)
        echo ${match[5]}
        echo ${match[10]}
    fi
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Accepted answer for being awk code - although the other answers are perfectly fine too. It happens though that the code that I am modifying is already awk, so inserting grep/perl would require a little more effort.

Comment: Glad you liked it. Added a bash-version as well just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -oP` to get both counts:

```
grep -oP '\d+(?= license)' file
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk doesn't capture regex groupings, but perl does:

```
perl -n -e'/Total of (\d+) licenses/ && print $1'
```

will print the number of licenses:

```
perl -n -e'/Total of (\d+) license/ && print $1'
```

will print the number of licenses in use.